# Mocap animation to Mixamo models animation?

Tags: motion-capture, mixamo

I retargeted the animation of a motion capture armature to a Mixamo armature with Rokoko and exported the animation as an FBX.
When I reassign that exported animation to another Mixamo rig's armature, the scale is different and the direction of movement is completely different. Does anyone know how to do this to fix this correctly?
I will attach here sample Mixamo rig and motion capture files.
https://we.tl/t-vCXE1nC3CR

[image]

Comment: If the bones have different names, orientations, if their relative location has changed, etc, they won't be played the same way, it's probably the problem here